# Indexing in Python using Array of indexes

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, vectorization

So, I have this matrix which is `M=60x8`.

Then I find for each line the max element using this `z= M.argmax(axis=1)`
Thus `z is a 60 element array` containing indexies from 0-7.

Apart from the old fashioned way to iterate with loops, could I use some sort of vectorised code in python in order to print the values of M where I got the max, using the z matrix.

Comment: You are looking for [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) . In particular, [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

# define our matrix M
M = np.arange(6*8).reshape(6,8)
```

When we look at M:

```
> M
> array(
  [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
   [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
   [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
   [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
   [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]])

> M.shape
> (6, 8)
```

Now we get the maximum arg of every row:

```
> z = np.argmax(M, axis=1)
> array([7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7])
```

Thus, we got the index of the max-element for each row. If we want to get back the values, we can simply slice through M:

```
> M[np.arange(M.shape[0]), z]
> array([ 7, 15, 23, 31, 39, 47])
```

`np.arange(M.shape[0])` creates indexes for each row, while `z` covers the indexes for the columns. Therefore, we are extracting the n-th element (according to the entries of `z`) of each row.

---

To prove this works for arbitrary "sorted" arrays:

```
> M2 = np.ravel(np.copy(M))
> np.random.shuffle(M2)
> M2 = M2.reshape(M.shape[0], M.shape[1])
> M2
> array(
  [[34, 16,  5, 32, 31,  2, 17, 38],
   [33, 18,  9, 46, 20,  4, 39, 30],
   [10, 41, 35, 23,  0, 24, 45, 14],
   [28, 36,  8, 22, 11, 15,  7, 44],
   [27,  1, 25,  6,  3, 19, 47, 37],
   [40, 42, 29, 21, 12, 43, 26, 13]])

> z2 = np.argmax(M2, axis=1)
> array([7, 3, 6, 7, 6, 5])

> M2[np.arange(M2.shape[0]), z2]
> array([38, 46, 45, 44, 47, 43])
```